# Can I access parent struct field?

Tags: go, sqlx

Is it possible to access a parent struct field so I can use it in the scan function? I want to have the `A` UUID in the Image string. So its `http://blah.com/images/a/04756596-7cf1-4ee0-bc6e-38677f2057e8/test.jpg`

```
a := models.A{}                                                                                                                                                                                
rows.StructScan(&a);
```

```
type A struct {                                                      
            UUID        uuid.UUID      `db:"uuid" json:"uuid"`
            Name        string         `db:"name" json:"name"`
            Image       Image          `db:"image" json:"image"`
}

type Image string

func (i *Image) Scan(value interface{}) error {
        if value == nil {
                *i = "https://picsum.photos/id/1029/400/150"
                return nil
        }

        b := fmt.Sprintf("%s/images/a/**{A.UUID HERE}**/%s",
                config.ServerConfig.BaseUrl, value.(string))

        *i = Image(b)

        return nil
}
```

If there is a better way to approach this I am all ears and any documentation on it is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "parent struct"?

Comment: I guess that was the wrong term. By that i mean the Image type is in the A struct and from the Image scan function i want to access the A structs UUID field

Comment: Well, `Scan` accepts an empty interface. So without a type assertion, you cannot access any specific fields of `value`.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this from a comment that has since been deleted.

Changed Image to a struct and added an ID field. Updated the sql statement to return the `A.UUID` as its self and as `image.id`

Abit of a hack but sqlx didnt like to populate two different struct fields that had the same `db` tag